# Want to implement WPF iframe just like on Asp.net

Tags: wpf-controls

I'm a newbie to WPF. I'm looking for a control that work like Asp.Net iframe in WPF. I want to have a static parent form which will call child forms and put them in this iframe. I want do it like Avast. Check the attached image. I want the parent form to occupy the gray and black area, and child form to occupy the white area. I want to call child form from the menu on the left. I want to have a child form for Status,Scan,Tools,Store, My devices,Help, Statistics and Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

WPF has a WebBrowser control you can use to load websites into your window.

Comment: Hi Robert. I don't want to load webpages, but WPF forms.

Comment: Ok in that case, what you are looking for is a custom "UserControl" which you can Google for and a find a ton of good tutorials.

Comment: I couldn't find it on google that's why i decided to come here. I want it to work like Avast. Check the attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Use Frame. It works like I-frame, but better.
To load a form just use `Frame.Navigate(yourClass);`